# error: '*p1' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?

Tags: c, qsort

```
int cmp_Player_name(Player **p1, Player **p2){
   if (*p1->name > p2->name){
      return 1;
   }
   if (p1->name < p2->name){
      return -1;
   }
   if (p1->name == p2->name){
      return 0;
   }
}
```

This is the function for qsort, This is my error:

error: '*p1' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?

How do i perform the comparison?

1. (*p1->name > *p2->name){
2. (*(*p1)->name
3. Initialize as a char and compare

But still cant not compare elements

Comment: probably you want to use `strcmp`

Comment: The signature is still incorrect -- the comparator parameters must be `void *` (or `void const *`). Check documentation for qsort

Answer (score 1):

This is C. There is no string-like type. There is no string comparison operator.
You are trying to compare pointers to character arrays (aka "string"), but not the arrays.
You should use strcmp() (or better: strncmp()) function here:

```
int cmp_Player_name(Player **p1, Player **p2) {
   return strcmp((*p1)->name, (*p2)->name);
}
```

Comment: This gives an error which i do not have yet understand and still on my learning phase.  'warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast'

Comment: Please show the definition of the `Player` structure. Probably you declared your `name` field as `char` instead of `char*`.